# Problems with using pytest and tf.test.TestCase simultaneously

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytest

I have a simple unit test where I check if I can instantiate my Tensorflow class with slightly different parameters. This seems like a great use case for `@pytest.mark.parametrize`.

However, I've discovered that `parametrize` is ignored if I my unit tests are methods of a `tf.test.TestCase`.

For example, when I run `pytest` on the following code:

```
class TestBasicRewardNet(tf.test.TestCase):                                                                                                                          
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("env", ['FrozenLake-v0', 'CartPole-v1',                                                                                               
        'CarRacing-v0', 'LunarLander-v2'])                                                                                                                           
    def test_init_no_crash(self, env):                                                                                                                               
        for i in range(3):                                                                                                                                    
            x = BasicRewardNet(env)
```

I get the error `TypeError: test_init_no_crash() missing 1 required positional argument: 'env'`.

To fix this issue, I tried just getting rid of the class wrapper, but that makes me miss out on some automatic Tensorflow test initialization. In particular, now every `BasicRewardNet` is built in the same TensorFlow graph, and so I need to do something like add a variable scope to avoid
conflicts. Adding in this variable scope seems hacky.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("env", ['FrozenLake-v0', 'CartPole-v1',                                                                                               
     'CarRacing-v0', 'LunarLander-v2'])  
def test_init_no_crash(env):                                                                                                                                         
    for i in range(3):                                                                                                                                               
        with tf.variable_scope(env+str(i)):                                                                                                                          
            x = BasicRewardNet(env)
```

I'm wondering if anyone knows a way I can cleanly get the best of both worlds? I'd like to be able to use `parametrize` and get the automatic Tensorflow initialization of `tf.test.TestCase` at the same time.

Comment: [The following `pytest` features do not work, and probably never will due to different design philosophies: ... Parametrization](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/unittest.html#pytest-features-in-unittest-testcase-subclasses). There are other parametrization techniques, like [`subTest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#distinguishing-test-iterations-using-subtests) (built-in in the stdlib since Python 3.4) or the [`parameterized`](https://pypi.org/project/parameterized/) library.

Comment: @hoefling Ah, thanks. These links are really helpful! `parameterized.expand` on `tf.test.TestCase` or using `tf.test.TestCase.subTest` sounds like good options.

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned in the comments by [hoefling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2650249/hoefling), it can be solved using `tf.test.TestCase.subTest`.

```
class TestBasicRewardNet(tf.test.TestCase):

    @staticmethod
    def my_sub_test(env):
        for i in range(3):                                                                                                                                               
            with tf.variable_scope(env+str(i)):                                                                                                                          
                x = BasicRewardNet(env)

    def test_init_no_crash(env):
        for env in ['FrozenLake-v0', 'CartPole-v1','CarRacing-v0', 'LunarLander-v2']:
            with self.subTest(env):                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                 self.my_sub_test(env)
```

To be able to use the `subTest` features when running with `pytest`, you should **add [pytest-subtests](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-subtests) in the requirements**, otherwise you won't have them!